# Import Zoom Call Logs data into PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, zoom-sdk

I can view api data in Postman from https://api.zoom.us/v2/phone/call_logs just fine but cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to pull the data in PowerBI through the Web Import. I get an authentication error or an error that says "A web API key can only be specified when a web API key name is provided."

Has anybody successfully pulled this data into PowerBI?

If I have

```
api key = 123
api secret = 456
verification token = 789
jwt token = abc
```

What goes where in PowerBI to get to the data?

Answer (score 0):

Where does Postman put the Web API Key?  If it's on the query string then specify the "web API Key Name" in the Web.Contents options record per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/web-contents).  And then configure the API Key in connection credentials.